# Catch a click in pyGTK

Tags: python, pygtk

Using http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/filelisting.py how can I detect a click on a filename and do something with it (like print this filename on the standard output)?

the file is here :

```
def make_list(self, dname=None):
    if not dname:
        self.dirname = os.path.expanduser('~')
    else:
        self.dirname = os.path.abspath(dname)
    self.window.set_title("Nitpicker : " + self.dirname)
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(self.dirname) if f[0] <> '.']
    files.sort()
    files = ['..'] + files
    listmodel = gtk.ListStore(object)
    for f in files:
        listmodel.append([f])
        return listmodel
```

In this last for loop, I could attach an event to **f** that triggers a function like

```
subprocess.call(["play", file])
```

But how could I do that ? How are clicks handled in pyGTK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found out :

```
def open_file(self, treeview, path, column):
    model = treeview.get_model()
    iter = model.get_iter(path)
    filename = os.path.join(self.dirname, model.get_value(iter, 0))
    filestat = os.stat(filename)
    # print filename
    if stat.S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode):
        new_model = self.make_list(filename)
        treeview.set_model(new_model)
    else:
        print filename + "is a file!!"
    return
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer. Thus future users know that this answer solved the problem.